# Template cannot evaluate database queryset django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am running through this wired issue. I hope I can describe it well.

#### The case:

Suppose that I am having the following types or identifiers:

```
classes = ['classa','classb','classc','classd']
```

and I am also having for each of the above class, these two subclasses:

```
subclasses = ['suba','subb']
```

Now, I am going to retrieve data points from the databased filtered on those classes and sub classes using a function in my model name it `get_data_filtered(a,b)` as follows:

```
context['custom-data'] = (
            {c: {subc: self.get_object().get_data_filtered(c,subc)} for c in
             classes for subc
             in subclasses})
```

When printing this context to the console on the view level, everything is fine. However, when passing it to the template and accessing it there, no data is retrieved!

When viewing the template using *Django Debug Toolbar*, the template context shows this:

```
context['custom-data']:'<<triggers database query>>'
```

The syntax in the template level is similar to:

```
{% for i in custom-data.classa.suba %}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

#### My analisis

I think the queryset never got evaluated this way. I also tried to put `.all()` and `list(...)` but getting nothing useful!

Can the queryset got evaluated this way?

If there is a better way to achieve such task please advice.

**Django version: 2.2**

Comment: how does `get_data_filtered` look like?

Comment: @Alex, It is just a one statement `filter ` on model objects.

Comment: Thats not helping; provide a code because most of the users don't have time to imagine a code

Comment: @Moha369, The whole post can be reduced to the following question: can the template render context having a key-value pair as `context['custom-data'] = {c{subc: ModelClass.objects.all()} for c in classes for subc in subclasses}`? In my case, it did not, while I am assuming it shall.

Comment: `context['custom-data'] = [c{subc : ModelClass.objects.all()} for c in classes for subc in subclasses]` should work for you, you should do that in a list not a dict

Comment: @Moha369, this will fire a syntax error!

Comment: in `c{sub..` the error says 'expected , or ]'

Comment: Makes sense, i am sorry. `{c : {subc : 5} for c in classes for subc in subclasses}`, but this will return something like `{class : { subclass : value }, another class : {subclass : value}}`

Comment: Because `c{dict}` is clearly not python valid statement

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for! Maybe I am not accessing it right in the template! I shall make access by keys! This makes some sense!

Comment: @Moha369, your observation was very helpful. It is working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Good, Good Luck in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I was not accessing the context in the template level properly. The access shall be by keys just as follows:

```
{% for c,subcdict in custom-data.items %}
    {% for subckey,objlist in subcdict.items %}
        {% for obj in objlist %}
            <p>{{ obj.prop }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for @moh369 observations in the post comments.